# using boost to compress and decompress gzip streams

Tags: c++, boost, compression, gzip

I want to use boost to (de)compress gzip streams (not files), so I wrote this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/copy.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/gzip.hpp>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   std::stringstream ss, comp, decomp;
   ss << "Hello World";

   boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf< boost::iostreams::input> in;
   in.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_compressor());
   in.push(ss);
   boost::iostreams::copy(in, comp);

   std::cout << "Compressed: ";
   std::cout << comp.str() << std::endl;

   boost::iostreams::filtering_streambuf<boost::iostreams::input> inbuf;
   inbuf.push(boost::iostreams::gzip_decompressor());
   inbuf.push(comp);
   boost::iostreams::copy(inbuf, decomp);

   std::cout << "Decompressed: ";
   std::cout << decomp.str() << std::endl;
}
```

It is aimed to first, compress an string and then decompress it to the original string. This code compiles just fine but when I execute it, the compression part works and prints its output but then for the decompression part, i get this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::iostreams::gzip_error> >'
what():  gzip error
Aborted (core dumped)
```

so can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

If I change the compressor and decompressor to bz2 format (using bzip2_compressor and bzip2_decompressor methods), the error will be gone and it will work just fine.

Comment: why the hell are you writing absolutely **everything** via the scope-operator??

Comment: @specializt He writes it via the keyboard I guess.

Comment: @specializt because copy paste, thats why.

Comment: @specializt I don't think that has anything to do with the actual problem??!

Comment: The provided code works for me exactly as written, using boost version 1.55.0. Best guess is that your version of zlib is a problem. Provide us with your OS, Boost, and zlib versions, as well as the command you used to compile.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange... I'm using kubuntu 14.04, boost 1.58 and zlib is updated to the last version in repository (installed it with apt-get), though I don't think boost has any external dependency to any other libraries. zlib must have been integrated in boost files and it is using that version of zlib. Hence I don't think upgrading zlib would have any effect on boost's work.

Comment: @Sinapse I was having the same problem. The problem was the file I was trying to read (the one I just wrote) was invalid. I was .push-ing an ostream when apparently I needed to be .push-ing a file_descriptor_sink.